# Regex to separate an ID after a specific word

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone please help in splitting an ID after a specific word in a URL. I need to delete a specific ID from URL and insert a custom ID.
The url goes like : `"/abc/mode/1234aqwer/mode1?query"`.
I need to replace `1234qwer` by `3456asdf`.

Example:

Input:

```
/abc/mode/1234aqwer/mode1?query
```

Output:

```
/abc/mode/3456asdf/mode1?query
```

Comment: Please tell us what language/tool you are using.  The exact answer would probably depend on that.

Comment: I'am using javascript

Comment: basically i need to extract and replace anything that comes after `mode`

Comment: Please show us clear input and output.  Currently your data won't even match properly.

Comment: Input: `/abc/mode/1234aqwer/mode1?query`
Output: `/abc/mode/3456asdf/mode1?query`

Comment: And would the target `1234aqwer` always be surrounded by path forward slashes on both sides?  Or, could it possible occur as a substring of a path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177534/discussion-between-gaurav-soni-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: It will always be surrounded by forward slashes

Comment: string.replace(new RegExp('\\d+'),3456);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `.replace` `/mode/` followed by non-slash characters, with `/mode/` and your desired replacement string:

```js
const input = '/abc/mode/1234aqwer/mode1?query';
console.log(
  input.replace(/\/mode\/[^\/]+/, '/mode/3456asdf')
);
```

Comment: Also if i want to extract `12334aqwer`  from `/abc/mode/1234aqwer/mode1?query` can u help me how can it be achieved?

Comment: Use `.match` instead, capture the repeated non-slashes in a group, and then get the first group from the resulting match object (`[1]`)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution without using `regex`. Use ES6's `replace` instead:

```js
url = "/abc/mode/1234aqwer/mode1?query"

replace = "1234aqwer"
replaceWith = "3456asdf"

console.log(url.replace(replace, replaceWith))
```